# Is my import still committing?

Tags: mysql, innodb, import, auto-commit

I'm importing around 9 million rows into my MySQL DB using the following command:

```
SET autocommit=0;
SOURCE my_import.sql;
COMMIT;
```

The command line is no longer outputting lines of `Query OK, X rows affected...`, and `SELECT COUNT(*)` query confirms that all the rows are there. Additionally, I'm no longer seeing an increase in my database size and the CPU/IOPS activity is very low.

However, I'm anxious that the command line cursor has not returned:

[image]

What could be going on here? Is it safe to assume that my import has finished and I can kill the terminal?

Comment: Did the script contain any `ALTER TABLE` commands ?

Answer (score 0):

I would be a little concerned. When you run `COMMIT;` you should get this

```
mysql> commit;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

If the prompt has not returned yet, run this

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

just to see if any queries are processing. Notwithstanding, MySQL could be still processing things. How ? Look at the InnoDB Architecture (Picture made by Percona CTO Vadim Tkachenko)

[image: InnoDB Plumbing]

If the prompt has not come back, I would assume the worst and just say the `COMMIT;` is not done. Even if a certain table stops increasing in size, you can still check for write activity directly in the OS.

For example, if you imported into a database called `mydb` and datadir is `/var/lib/mysql`, do this:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/mydb
watch "ls -l --time-style=+\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\" | grep ibd$ | head -20"
```

This will poll your `.ibd` files for the latest one that received changes from the dirty pages of the InnoDB Buffer Pool. You could also check the timestamp of ibdata1 because it was to receive writes to the Insert Buffer and DoubleWrite Buffer just to see if it has activity.

If nothing seems to be moving, you may have to bite the bullet and hit Ctrl-C if you are tired of waiting. Although you ran `SELECT COUNT(*)` and got the correct count, that count might be based on the existing rows still lingering in the dirty pages of the InnoDB Buffer Pool (perhaps the `SELECT` is doing a phantom read).

I would just hit Ctrl-C and check the table count.

You could also check the the dirty pages after hitting Ctrl-C.

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool%dirty';
+--------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                  | Value |
+--------------------------------+-------+
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty | ...   |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty | ...   |
+--------------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

If the dirty pages rapidly start decreasing after hitting Ctrl-C, you will have to reimport without using `autocommit=0;`

This is as far as I can tell you without knowing the contents of the script.